# Get the inequalities from answers

Tags: equation-solving, inequalities

I have two inequality.

> x1 >= x2
>
> x1 >= x3
>
> x1,x2,x3 ∈ {0,1}

the answer of the Inequalities is

> (x1,x2,x3) ∈ {(0,0,0),(1,0,0),(1,1,0),(1,0,1)}

How to get the Inequalities from our answers?(reverse the above process)

Is there any algorithm?

Comment: Do you also want to recover `x1,x2,x3 ∈ {0,1}` from the solutions?  I have neglected that aspect at present but your question appears to focus on inequalities only so I did not address it.

Answer (score 6):

First of all I get five solutions for your system from Solve:

```
m = {x1, x2, x3} /. 
  Solve[{x1 >= x2, x1 >= x3, ##} & @@ (# == 0 || # == 1 & /@ {x1, x2, x3})]
```

> ```
> {{0, 0, 0}, {1, 0, 0}, {1, 0, 1}, {1, 1, 0}, {1, 1, 1}}
> ```

From that output I can compute inequality relations like this:

```
Union /@ Sign[ Subtract @@@ Subsets[m\[Transpose], {2}] ]
```

> ```
> {{0, 1}, {0, 1}, {-1, 0, 1}}
> ```

The output aligns with:

```
Subsets[{x1, x2, x3}, {2}]
```

> ```
> {{x1, x2}, {x1, x3}, {x2, x3}}
> ```

So a final result can be had with:

```
fn[in_, {a_, b_}] := Or @@ in /. {-1 :> a < b, 0 :> a == b, 1 :> a > b}

And @@ MapThread[fn, {
    {{0, 1}, {0, 1}, {-1, 0, 1}},
    Subsets[{x1, x2, x3}, {2}]
   }]

Simplify[%]
```

> ```
> x1 >= x2 && x1 >= x3
> ```

### Self-contained function

*Update 2: I changed `signToIneq` seeking greater performance.*

```
ineqFromSols[m_] /; MatrixQ[m, NumericQ] :=
  Module[{signToIneq, pair, n = Length @ First @ m},
    pair = Subsets[#, {2}] &;
    signToIneq[si_, {a_, b_}] := Switch[si,
      {-1}, a < b, {0}, a == b, {1}, a > b, {-1, 0}, a <= b, {0, 1}, a >= b, _, True
     ];
    Subtract @@@ pair[ m\[Transpose] ]
      // Sign
      // Map[Union]
      // And @@ MapThread[signToIneq, {#, pair @ Array[C, n]}] &
  ]

ineqFromSols[{{0, 0, 0}, {1, 0, 0}, {1, 0, 1}, {1, 1, 0}, {1, 1, 1}}]
```

> ```
> C[1] >= C[2] && C[1] >= C[3]
> ```

---

#### A refactoring of LouisB's approach

There is a certain direct elegance to LouisB's approach but I find that elegance somewhat obfuscated.  Therefore I offer a refactoring of his code which I hope demonstrates cleanliness and brevity, and which provides easier extension to more than three variables.

```
solns = {{0, 0, 0}, {1, 0, 0}, {1, 1, 0}, {1, 0, 1}};
set = {x1, x2, x3};

relations = {# < #2, # <= #2, # > #2, # >= #2} &;
eqns = Join @@ relations @@@ Subsets[set, {2}];
rules = Thread[set -> #] & /@ solns;

Select[eqns, And @@ (# /. rules) &]
```

> ```
> {x1 >= x2, x1 >= x3}
> ```

Answer (score 4):

**Initial Version**

Here is one approach to finding a set of inequations that have the given solutions.  In this version we seek only inequations that have the `<` and `<=` relations.

```
solns = {{0, 0, 0}, {1, 0, 0}, {1, 1, 0}, {1, 0, 1}};
relations = {Less, LessEqual};
eqns = Table[If[TrueQ[x[[1]] == x[[2]]], Nothing[], r[x[[1]], x[[2]]]],
    {r, relations},
    {x, Tuples[{x1, x2, x3}, 2]}] // Flatten;
rules = Table[{x1 -> s[[1]], x2 -> s[[2]], x3 -> s[[3]]}, 
    {s, solns}];
mask = (And @@ (# /. rules)) & /@ eqns;
Pick[eqns, mask] // Column

(*  { x2 <= x1, x3 <= x1 }  *)
```

In the above, first we write the known solutions for `x1, x2, x3`.  Second, we write a list of the relations we want to use in our equations.  Third, we create a list of all the equations that can be formed using the relations and the 3 unknowns.  Fourth, we create a list of rules that substitute a known solution into all of the equations.  Fifth, the mask tells us which equations are true for all of the known solutions.  Lastly, we pick the equations for which the mask is true.

Could be generalized to more variables.

**Improved Version**

Here is a refinement based on Mr.Wizard's valuable insight.  In this version we allow both equations and inequations by defining 6 `relations`.  All ordered `pairs` of the variables are considered.  The `ineqns` (one of them is an equation) are formed by applying each relation to each ordered pair of variables.  The `rules` are used to replace the variables in each inequation with the known solutions.  We select the inequations that satisfy all of the rules.

```
ClearAll["Global`*"]

solns = {{0, 0, 0}, {1, 0, 0}, {1, 1, 0}, {1, 0, 1}};
vars = {x1, x2, x3};

relations = {# < #2, # <= #2, # == #2, # > #2, # >= #2, # != #2} &;
pairs = Join[#, Reverse /@ #] &@Subsets[vars, {2}];
ineqns = Join @@ relations @@@ pairs;
rules = Thread[vars -> #] & /@ solns;

result = Select[ineqns, And @@ (# /. rules) &]

(*  {x1 >= x2, x1 >= x3, x2 <= x1, x3 <= x1 }  *)
```

We note that the `result` contains 4 inequations.

**A Variation**

An interesting variation of the above is to use `pairs = Subsets[vars, {2}];` The `result` is then `{ x1 >= x2, x1 >= x3 }` with 2 greater thans.

We can test this variation with the same solution in a different order.  Instead of $x_1,x_2,x_3$ we give the same solutions in the order $x_2,x_3,x_1$.  That is, we test the variation with

```
solns = {{0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 1}, {1, 0, 1}, {0, 1, 1}};
vars = {x2, x3, x1};
```

and obtain the different result `{x2 <= x1, x3 <= x1}`, which has 2 less thans.  We could also use the following order

```
solns = {{0, 0, 0}, {0, 1, 0}, {0, 1, 1}, {1, 1, 0}};
vars = {x3, x1, x2};
```

to obtain a third result `{x3 <= x1, x1 >= x2}` with 1 less than and 1 greater than.

Since the variation that produces 2 inequations is sensitive to the order of the input variables, the "improved version" that produces 4 inequations is preferred.

Comment: I believe I can significantly refactor this code.  Would you like to put that in my own answer, in your answer as an addendum, or directly edit your code?

Comment: For the time being I put it as an addendum to my answer so I don't lose it.  You may review it and decide what you would like me to do with it. (And tell me if I broke anything.)

Comment: @Mr.Wizard  Many thanks for the refactored version.  I used it in the update to my answer.